# What is difference between WebUtility.HtmlEncode and AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1, antixsslibrary

AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode have support only for .Net framework.
Can I use WebUtility.HtmlEncode for Antixss as we have our application in .net core 2.1?

Comment: AntiXss is exactly what the name denotes, its to protect your application against cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks and LDAP injection attacks, in core you should read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cross-site-scripting?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: What is your use case and your problem so that we can help you identify which to use and why

Comment: I am 90% sure that AntiXssEncoder's "extra" encoding has been incorporated into `WebUtility`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cross-site-scripting?view=aspnetcore-3.1#customizing-the-encoders states `By default encoders use a safe list limited to the Basic Latin Unicode range and encode all characters outside of that range as their character code equivalents.` Based on that, it is very safe to use (since it is whitelist, not blacklist, based). Don't stress about it.

Comment: Although https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Net/WebUtility.cs#L319 makes me slightly less confident about my above comment. ;) Is using https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6072e4d3a7a2a1493f514cdf4be75a3d56580e84/src/libraries/System.Text.Encodings.Web/src/System/Text/Encodings/Web/HtmlEncoder.cs#L20 instead an option?

Comment: @mjwills https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cross-site-scripting?view=aspnetcore-3.1#customizing-the-encoders has support for 3.1 and I need similar library for .net core 2.1

Comment: @SimonPrice I want to protect my application against xss in version .net core 2.1

Comment: @mjwills This does not have support for 2.1

Answer (score 8):

## TL;DR:

> AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode have support only for .Net framework. Can I use WebUtility.HtmlEncode for Antixss as we have our application in .net core 2.1?

**Correct**.

But I want to stress that *there is no-such thing* as an "anti-XSS HTML-encoder" because **all** correctly-implemented HTML-encoders *will* protect your website from XSS attacks *when used correctly*.

- <sub>(I don't know why Microsoft named it `AntiXssEncoder`, but given that at-the-time the main `HtmlEncode` implentation was actually buggy and insecure probably might have something to do with it, but that's *ancient-history* now.)</sub>

In .NET Core 2.1, you *only* need to use `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode`.

In other .NET releases (especially historical versions), things are complicated, read on if you dare...

## Why `AntiXssEncoder` (aka `AntiXss` and `AntiXss.Encoder`)  exists - and why it's obsolete in 2021:

- The `AntiXssEncoder` class from the `AntiXss` NuGet package (aka `Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss`) **is obsolete** (and has been since 2014) when it was moved to `System.Web.Security.AntiXss`.

  - The other classes: `AntiXssEncoder`, `Encoder`, and `AntiXss` are just alternative APIs for the same underlying implementation in `Encoder` btw.
- The `AntiXssEncoder` in `System.Web.Security.AntiXss` is not available in .NET Core 2.1. However this is not a *significant* problem:

  - The original `Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss` was created because `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` was considered insecure because it did not encode single-apostrophe characters, so XSS attacks were possible against ASP.NET 1.x and ASP.NET 2.x WebForms (`.aspx`) pages that used single-apostrophes to delimit HTML attributes that contained user-specified values.

    - For example:

      ```
      String userProvidedValue = "bad.gif' onerror='alert()";
      <img src='<%= this.Server.HtmlEncode( userProvidedValue ) %>' />
      ```

      ...which will be rendered as:

      ```
      <img src='bad.gif' onerror='alert()' />
      ```
    - However this issue was fixed in ASP.NET 4.0 when `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` was corrected to also HTML-encode those apostrophes. So the exact same code above will now be rendered as below, which *won't* show an `alert()`:

      ```
      <img src='bad.gif&#39; onerror=&#39;alert()' />
      ```
  - `AntiXssEncoder` also supported specifying a list of excluded Unicode code-points or `Char` values, this was added because `AntiXssEncoder` defaulted to hex-encoding *all* `Char` values (not code-points!) above 0xFFFF, which unfortunately meant that even *completely safe* text in Arabic, Hebrew, Kanji, etc would be escaped, making the raw HTML almost unreadable and ballooning the output HTML length.

    - For example the (gibberish) string `"لك أن كلا"` would be rendered as `"&#x644;&#x643; &#x623;&#x646; &#x643;&#x644;&#x627;"` - which isn't good.
    - Fortunately `AntiXssEncoder.MarkAsSafe` can be used to exclude character ranges at the programmer's discretion.
    - By the time .NET Core 2.1 came out, the `System.Net.WebUtility` class (not to be confused with `System.Web.HttpUtility`, of course) was improved so that it does not unnecessarily hex-encode high `Char` values and it *does* also HTML-encode apostrophes, hence why `AntiXssEncoder` was no-longer needed.
- In .NET Core 3.1 (and later, including .NET 5 and .NET 6) things improved further, but also got a bit confusing...

  - Things got better [because `System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder` was added](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodings.web.htmlencoder?view=net-6.0). This is a separate implementation (instead of simply wrapping `WebUtility`) which brings back `AntiXssEncoder`'s ability to exclude ranges of characters from encoding *just in case* you need that functionality. But it's a bit of an edge-case, imo.

    - You can do this by calling `HtmlEncoder.Create(TextEncoderSettings)` with a configured `TextEncoderSettings` object with the required char ranges excluded.
- In .NET Core 3.1, for the sake of back-compat, [Microsoft brought back `System.Web.HttpUtility`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility?view=net-6.0), however this is just another wrapper over `WebUtility.HtmlEncode`.

  - It does also have `HtmlAttributeEncode` - which **does not** encode single-apostrophes. There is *no good reason* to use this method, imo. I'm surprised Microsoft hasn't annotated it with `[Obsolete]`, actually.
- However, in .NET Core (and .NET 5 and later) there isn't any way to HTML encode text such that *named entities* are used instead of hex-encoded entities (other than `&lt;`, `&gtl` and `&amp;`).

  - Previously, the `AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode` (both `Microsoft.Security` and `System.Web.Security`) method had a the `useNamedEntities` parameter which involved a large hard-coded table of known entity names, e.g. `£` becomes `&pound;` instead of `&#127;`.

    - I imagine they removed this functionality because you cannot safely used named-entities unless *all other software* in your HTML-processing pipeline also supports it, and given [it's a *large* table](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html#named-character-references) I expect that lots of people had issues with it breaking poorly-updated downstream code.
    - The HTML Living Standard (aka "HTML5") calls them [*character references*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#character-references) instead of "entities" (a holdover from SGML DTDs) and defines the `&#nnnn;`-syntax as means of encoding [Unicode code-points *specifically*](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#code-point) as opposed to a character-value in some other encoding scheme, whereas previously in HTML4 the spec refers to ISO 10646 (aka *UCS*) characters *which is not Unicode as we know it today*. (and I suspect that browsers may have tried to map characters based on the document's encoding/code-page if the page wasn't encoded using Unicode (like Shift-JIS), but I might be wrong).

---

Finally, here's a table comparing the output from all of the different `HtmlEncode` methods found in .NET as of 2021:

### `HtmlEncode` methods available in .NET Framework 4.8

- Note that the following `HtmlEncode` methods are excluded because they're just wrappers over other implementations:

  - `System.Web.HttpServerUtility` (aka `Server.HtmlEncode`) just forwards to `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`.
  - `System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter.WriteEncodedText` also forwards to `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`.
  - `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`:

    - In ASP.NET 1.x and ASP.NET 2.0 (2001 and 2005 respectively) this is incorrectly implemented such that it does not escape apostrophes. I've included  results from *that* implementation in the "System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode (ASP.NET 1.1 and 2.0)" column, for historical curiosity.
    - In ASP.NET 4.x, the `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` method just forwards to `System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.Current.HtmlEncode(s)`

      - Note that `System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.**Current**` can be replaced at runtime, which is how an update to ASP.NET 4.x (I forget which) was able to make almost everyone use (the then far-better) `AntiXssEncoder` without people needing to change their existing application code. *Neat*.
      - Also note that `System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.**Current**` can point to any compatible implementation, while ``` System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.**Default**`` is _always_ just a wrapper over ``` WebUtility.HtmlEncode`.
  - `System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.Default` - as mentioned above, this is just another `System.Net.WebUtility` wrapper.

| # | Input | Code-point(s) | UTF-8 bytes | UTF-16 bytes | `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode` | `System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder` | `System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(false)` | `System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(true)` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `0` | `abc` | `U+0061 U+0062 U+0063` | `61 62 63` | `61 00 62 00 63 00` | `abc` | `abc` | `abc` | `abc` |
| `1` | `<` | `U+003C` | `3C` | `3C 00` | `&lt;` | `&lt;` | `&lt;` | `&lt;` |
| `2` | `>` | `U+003E` | `3E` | `3E 00` | `&gt;` | `&gt;` | `&gt;` | `&gt;` |
| `3` | `&` | `U+0026` | `26` | `26 00` | `&amp;` | `&amp;` | `&amp;` | `&amp;` |
| `4` | `"` | `U+0022` | `22` | `22 00` | `&quot;` | `&quot;` | `&quot;` | `&quot;` |
| `5` | `'` | `U+0027` | `27` | `27 00` | `&#39;` | `&#x27;` | `&#39;` | `&#39;` |
| `6` | `Ÿ` | `U+009F` | `C2 9F` | `9F 00` | `Ÿ` | `&#x9F;` | `&#159;` | `&#159;` |
| `7` |  | `U+00A0` | `C2 A0` | `A0 00` | `&#160;` | `&#xA0;` | `&#160;` | `&nbsp;` |
| `8` | `ÿ` | `U+00FF` | `C3 BF` | `FF 00` | `&#255;` | `&#xFF;` | `ÿ` | `&yuml;` |
| `9` | `ā` | `U+0101` | `C4 81` | `01 01` | `ā` | `&#x101;` | `ā` | `ā` |
| `10` | `~` | `U+007E` | `7E` | `7E 00` | `~` | `~` | `~` | `~` |
| `11` | `` | `U+007F` | `7F` | `7F 00` | `` | `&#x7F;` | `&#127;` | `&#127;` |  |  |  |  |
| `12` | `£` | `U+00A3` | `C2 A3` | `A3 00` | `&#163;` | `&#xA3;` | `£` | `&pound;` |
| `13` | `ÿ` | `U+00FF` | `C3 BF` | `FF 00` | `&#255;` | `&#xFF;` | `ÿ` | `&yuml;` |
| `14` | `Ḃ` | `U+1E02` | `E1 B8 82` | `02 1E` | `Ḃ` | `&#x1E02;` | `&#7682;` | `&#7682;` |
| `15` |  | `U+1F4A9` | `F0 9F 92 A9` | `3D D8 A9 DC` | `&#128169;` | `&#x1F4A9;` | `&#128169;` | `&#128169;` |
| `16` |  | `U+233B4` | `F0 A3 8E B4` | `4C D8 B4 DF` | `&#144308;` | `&#x233B4;` | `&#144308;` | `&#144308;` |
| `17` |  | `U+233B4` | `F0 A3 8E B4` | `4C D8 B4 DF` | `&#144308;` | `&#x233B4;` | `&#144308;` | `&#144308;` |
| `18` | `لك أن كلا` | `U+0644 U+0643 U+0020 U+0623 U+0646 U+0020 U+0643 U+0644 U+0627` | `D9 84 D9 83 20 D8 A3 D9 86 20 D9 83 D9 84 D8 A7` | `44 06 43 06 20 00 23 06 46 06 20 00 43 06 44 06 27 06` | `لك أن كلا` | `&#x644;&#x643; &#x623;&#x646; &#x643;&#x644;&#x627;` | `&#1604;&#1603; &#1571;&#1606; &#1603;&#1604;&#1575;` | `&#1604;&#1603; &#1571;&#1606; &#1603;&#1604;&#1575;` |

#### Obsolete and historical `HtmlEncode` methods:

This table is included only for *computer-archeological* reasons. **It does not apply to .NET Framework 4.8, nor any versions of ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET-for-.NET 5 or later.

| # | Input | Code-point(s) | UTF-8 bytes | UTF-16 bytes | `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode (ASP.NET 1.1 and 2.0)` | `Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(false)` | `Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(true)` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `0` | `abc` | `U+0061 U+0062 U+0063` | `61 62 63` | `61 00 62 00 63 00` | `abc` | `abc` | `abc` |
| `1` | `<` | `U+003C` | `3C` | `3C 00` | `&lt;` | `&lt;` | `&lt;` |
| `2` | `>` | `U+003E` | `3E` | `3E 00` | `&gt;` | `&gt;` | `&gt;` |
| `3` | `&` | `U+0026` | `26` | `26 00` | `&amp;` | `&amp;` | `&amp;` |
| `4` | `"` | `U+0022` | `22` | `22 00` | `&quot;` | `&quot;` | `&quot;` |
| `5` | `'` | `U+0027` | `27` | `27 00` | `'` | `&#39;` | `&#39;` |
| `6` | `Ÿ` | `U+009F` | `C2 9F` | `9F 00` | `Ÿ` | `&#159;` | `&#159;` |
| `7` |  | `U+00A0` | `C2 A0` | `A0 00` | `&#160;` | `&#160;` | `&nbsp;` |
| `8` | `ÿ` | `U+00FF` | `C3 BF` | `FF 00` | `&#255;` | `ÿ` | `&yuml;` |
| `9` | `ā` | `U+0101` | `C4 81` | `01 01` | `ā` | `ā` | `ā` |
| `10` | `~` | `U+007E` | `7E` | `7E 00` | `~` | `~` | `~` |
| `11` | `` | `U+007F` | `7F` | `7F 00` | `` | `&#127;` | `&#127;` |  |  |  |  |
| `12` | `£` | `U+00A3` | `C2 A3` | `A3 00` | `&#163;` | `£` | `&pound;` |
| `13` | `ÿ` | `U+00FF` | `C3 BF` | `FF 00` | `&#255;` | `ÿ` | `&yuml;` |
| `14` | `Ḃ` | `U+1E02` | `E1 B8 82` | `02 1E` | `Ḃ` | `&#7682;` | `&#7682;` |
| `15` |  | `U+1F4A9` | `F0 9F 92 A9` | `3D D8 A9 DC` |  | `&#128169;` | `&#128169;` |
| `16` |  | `U+233B4` | `F0 A3 8E B4` | `4C D8 B4 DF` |  | `&#144308;` | `&#144308;` |
| `17` |  | `U+233B4` | `F0 A3 8E B4` | `4C D8 B4 DF` |  | `&#144308;` | `&#144308;` |
| `18` | `لك أن كلا` | `U+0644 U+0643 U+0020 U+0623 U+0646 U+0020 U+0643 U+0644 U+0627` | `D9 84 D9 83 20 D8 A3 D9 86 20 D9 83 D9 84 D8 A7` | `44 06 43 06 20 00 23 06 46 06 20 00 43 06 44 06 27 06` | `لك أن كلا` | `&#1604;&#1603; &#1571;&#1606; &#1603;&#1604;&#1575;` | `&#1604;&#1603; &#1571;&#1606; &#1603;&#1604;&#1575;` |

#### `HtmlEncode` methods in .NET 5

| # | Input | Code-point / Runes | UTF-8 bytes | UTF-16 bytes | `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode` | `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode (.NET 5)` | `System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `0` | `abc` | `97 98 99` | `61 62 63` | `61 00 62 00 63 00` | `abc` | `abc` | `abc` |
| `1` | `<` | `60` | `3C` | `3C 00` | `&lt;` | `&lt;` | `&lt;` |
| `2` | `>` | `62` | `3E` | `3E 00` | `&gt;` | `&gt;` | `&gt;` |
| `3` | `&` | `38` | `26` | `26 00` | `&amp;` | `&amp;` | `&amp;` |
| `4` | `"` | `34` | `22` | `22 00` | `&quot;` | `&quot;` | `&quot;` |
| `5` | `'` | `39` | `27` | `27 00` | `&#39;` | `&#39;` | `&#x27;` |
| `6` | `Ÿ` | `159` | `C2 9F` | `9F 00` | `Ÿ` | `Ÿ` | `&#x9F;` |
| `7` |  | `160` | `C2 A0` | `A0 00` | `&#160;` | `&#160;` | `&#xA0;` |
| `8` | `ÿ` | `255` | `C3 BF` | `FF 00` | `&#255;` | `&#255;` | `&#xFF;` |
| `9` | `ā` | `257` | `C4 81` | `01 01` | `ā` | `ā` | `&#x101;` |
| `10` | `~` | `126` | `7E` | `7E 00` | `~` | `~` | `~` |
| `11` | `` | `127` | `7F` | `7F 00` | `` | `` | `&#x7F;` |  |  |  |  |
| `12` | `£` | `163` | `C2 A3` | `A3 00` | `&#163;` | `&#163;` | `&#xA3;` |
| `13` | `ÿ` | `255` | `C3 BF` | `FF 00` | `&#255;` | `&#255;` | `&#xFF;` |
| `14` | `Ḃ` | `7682` | `E1 B8 82` | `02 1E` | `Ḃ` | `Ḃ` | `&#x1E02;` |
| `15` |  | `128169` | `F0 9F 92 A9` | `3D D8 A9 DC` | `&#128169;` | `&#128169;` | `&#x1F4A9;` |
| `16` |  | `144308` | `F0 A3 8E B4` | `4C D8 B4 DF` | `&#144308;` | `&#144308;` | `&#x233B4;` |
| `17` |  | `144308` | `F0 A3 8E B4` | `4C D8 B4 DF` | `&#144308;` | `&#144308;` | `&#x233B4;` |
| `18` | `لك أن كلا` | `1604 1603 32 1571 1606 32 1603 1604 1575` | `D9 84 D9 83 20 D8 A3 D9 86 20 D9 83 D9 84 D8 A7` | `44 06 43 06 20 00 23 06 46 06 20 00 43 06 44 06 27 06` | `لك أن كلا` | `لك أن كلا` | `&#x644;&#x643; &#x623;&#x646; &#x643;&#x644;&#x627;` |